# How to define the background color of this side menu?

Tags: html, css, menu

I've added a side menu successfully but when i want to change the color of it it doesn't work.
The mid of the menu is still another grey and i dont know what to do.
Tried to add `style="background-color: grey;"` but it didn't made any difference.

[The Site I'm talking about](http://ni631939_1.vweb06.nitrado.net/subpage.html)

Comment: Questions about CSS are usually better suited for StackOverflow.com because there are many more programmers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the middle grey colour, in the CSS look for the following block of code:

```
.sidebar-nav li {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

then change the background line to whatever colour you want using that syntax or using the normal syntax:

```
background-color: #F5F5F5;
```